# How to position an image to the right of a center aligned title with HTML & CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a HTML page, and I've run into a little problem. Here's a picture about what I want: https://i.imgsafe.org/2c4d808.png

I've got a header section which contains the title and the picture, but I can't move the picture into the right side (red area) of the header.

**I need to meet these conditions:**

1. The title and the picture must be in the same div (header), however I can use nested divs in the header.
2. The title must be centered.
3. The picture must be completely on the right side of the header (both have a height of 100px).

The header is 800x100 px and the picture is 160x100 px.

I can modify anything in my HTML or CSS code.

Just to be clear: The header is with the "TITLE TITLE TITLE TITLE" and it is blue.

```css
#container{
    width: 800px;
    height: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto; 
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #cccccc;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px black;
}

#header{
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #6495ED;
}

#menu{
    width: 150px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: #FFD700;
    float: left;
}

#main{
    width: 650px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: #00FF00;
    float: right;
}

#footer{
    height: 80px;
    clear: both;
    background-color: #6495ED;
}

#footerwords{
    float: right;
}

#headerpics{
    positioning: absolute;
    top: 0px;
}



      ul{
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-family: arial;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="header">
        <h1><center>TITLE TITLE TITLE TITLE</center><h1>
      <div id = "headerpics">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/160x100/E8117F/ffffff/?text=Books" />
      </div>
  </div>  
      <div id = "main">xx t xx </div>
      <div id = "menu">
        <ul>
          <li><a href = "index.html">1111111</a></li>
          <li><a href = "#">2222222</a></li>
          <li><a href = "#">33333333</a></li>
          <li><a href = "#">4444444</a></li>
          <li><a href = "#">5555555</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div id = "footer">
        <div id = "footerwords">
          <strong></br>footer........<strong> 
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Could you provide your current code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

give the <div> that holds the text/img a position: relative;

then give the <img> a position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0;

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
.masthead {
  position: relative;
  height:139px;
  background-color: #9cc;
}
.masthead-img {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="masthead">
  <h1>This is My Title</h1>
  <img src="http://placekitten.com.s3.amazonaws.com/homepage-samples/200/139.jpg" alt="" class="masthead-img" />
</div>
```

Comment: Can you help me, how should it exactly look like? I just posted my code. I'm a little confused about the "picture" and "img" you' re mentioning.

Comment: sure.  Making one now.

Comment: by the way, you can't use a <center> inside of an h1.  Two reasons: 1) center is not allowed as a child of an h1, and 2) center has been deprecated with HTML5.

Comment: Actually, the center element is obsolete as of HTML5 https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html#non-conforming-features

Comment: Yup, that's what I meant by deprecated.